# Android Process Synchronization

Tags: android, process, synchronization

Are the processes in android asynchronous? If they are asynchronous then how can we conclude when the activity or process is finished or completed its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the processes in android
>   asynchronous?

Processes are neither synchronous or asynchronous, in any operating system. *Forking* processes is frequently asynchronous.

Since, at the SDK level, you are generally unaware of what is going on in terms of processes, this question is moot for Android. Besides, just about everything in Android is asynchronous -- `startActivity()`, for example.

> how can we conclude when the activity
>   or process is finished or completed
>   its execution.

Generally, you should not care.

You can specially construct a pair of activities, where the first activity uses `startActivityForResult()` and the second activity calls `setResult()`. Then, the first activity will be called with `onActivityResult()` to supply the result from the second activity. The result is triggered when the second activity closes (e.g., second activity calls `finish()`, user presses BACK button).

Answer (score 0):

The [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#procs) developer documentation explains Android processes, threads, and lifecycle events.